# Proof of the Induced Orientation on a Boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the below proof from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, why is the determinant of the transition matrix between $(N_p, \partial_{x^1}|_p, \dots, \partial_{x^{n-1}}|_p)$, $(\tilde{N}_p, \partial_{x^1}|_p, \dots, \partial_{x^{n-1}}|_p)$ equal to $N^n(p)/\tilde{N}^n(p)$?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix which takes the basis $(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n)$ to the basis $(N_p,\partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n-1})$, when written in the $(\partial_1,\dots,\partial_n)$ basis, is in fact the matrix $(N_p,\partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n-1})$ itself.

Thus the matrix which takes the vectors $(\tilde{N}_p,\partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n-1})$ to the vectors $(N_p,\partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n-1})$ looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
N_p^1 & 1 & \dotsm & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
N_p^{n-1} & 0 & \dotsm & 1 \\
N_p^n & 0 & \dotsm & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde N_p^1 & 1 & \dotsm & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\tilde N_p^{n-1} & 0 & \dotsm & 1 \\
\tilde N_p^n & 0 & \dotsm & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{~ -1}
$$
which has determinant
$$
\det[\,\bullet\,]\frac{1}{\det[\,\tilde{\bullet}\,]}
= (-1)^{n-1}N_p^n \cdot \frac{1}{(-1)^{n-1}\tilde N_p^n}
$$